# How to revert to Windows 7 after installing Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8-preview

I was a little gung-ho with my installation of W8 and installed it on my main PC. How do I revert to W7, keeping programs etc?

Comment: Ouch.  It's called a 'Developer Preview' for a reason...

Comment: I think it's called "Premature Installation".

Comment: Gung-ho, indeed. LOL @ premature installation. It's OK; it affects all of us at some point.

Comment: These lessons are good.  You live and you learn.  A $50 500GB harddrive makes for a good investment here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> You can't uninstall the Windows Developer Preview. To reinstall your previous operating system, you must have restore or installation media.

See "Notes about Installing The Developer Preview"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

You may have a "windows.old" folder on the C drive, this will contain all your files that were in the W7 installation, unless you formatted the partition prior to installing W8.

Answer (score 6):

As @Moab said

> You may have a `windows.old` file on the C drive, this will contain
> all your files that were in the Windows 7 installation, unless you formatted
> the partition prior to installing Windows 8 Developer Preview.

Using [this article from Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971760/) you can recover data from `windows.old` file. The summary for the article says

> This article describes how to **manually restore a previous Windows
> installation** on the computer to replace the current Windows Vista
> installation.
>
> To do this, you must use the command prompt, and you must type
> specific commands at the command prompt to rename and to move folders
> between the different versions of Windows.
>
> This article is intended for a beginning to intermediate  computer
> user.

The article is intended for Windows Vista, but **you can follow the steps and see if it still applies for reverting from Windows 8 Developer Preview to Windows 7.**

Comment: Very helpful addition. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

GOING BACK TO WINDOWS 7 from WINDOWS 8

As an engineer, I was curious about Windows 8. Thus I bought Windows 8 online directly from Microsoft which automatically was setup on my USB thumb drive. I did a BIOS update on my computer, also saved an image of my Windows 7 system (VERY SMART STEP!) and then I was ready. I choose to do a clean windows 8 install! Played with Windows 8 for a month and realized what a mess.

So then, I thought, its time to put Windows 7 back on my computer. This should be simple. Just restore my Windows 7 image. WRONG ! ! ! !

You have no idea how many problems and errors I discovered. There were so many I did not even keep track of all the error codes and everything that would not work. And I was armed with everything: I had a Windows 7 bootable USB recovery drive, a Windows 8 bootable install/recovery USB drive, a Windows 7 image file, and the latest and greatest BIOS. All were of no help !

What I discovered was that Windows 8 changes your hard drive from MBR to GPT (boot sector) and each one does not like the other. Thus you CANNOT boot a Windows 7 recovery USB drive AND/OR do a Windows 7  image restore if your hard drive is set as a GPT volume/disk; likewise, you CANNOT do a Windows 7 MBR image recovery from a Windows 8 recovery bootable USB drive.

After spending 16 straight hours of research and work on this problem, I finally found the solution. It's a painful solution but it works.

What I had to do is: (this assumes you installed Windows 8 and thus your hard drive is set as GPT)

see:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26203-convert-gpt-disk-mbr-disk.html

- boot up from your Windows 8 recovery/install USB drive and enter into COMMAND PROMPT (NOTE: this is not starting up the entire Windows 8 operating system)
- you MUST manually delete all volumes on the primary disk that is listed on your hard drive (do research using 'diskpart' and also 'delete partition' and 'delete volume' commands. I think I finally had to use the delete partition command)
- Then execute a 'convert mbr' command to the primary disk

Once you know that GPT is gone, your set! Just reboot using a Windows 7 recovery USB/CD drive and select restore an image (Windows 7 image). It works! You now have Windows 7 back.

You could try using the original Windows 7 install CDs, but my new laptop does not have a CD player.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](http://addsiteurl.net/blog/2012/03/how-to-revert-to-windows-7-after-installing-windows-8/) explains how to do it:

> First of all the Windows 8 Developer Preview version doesn’t have any
>   option of reverting it back to previous version of OS,you will
>   therefore need some manual process that includes reformatting your
>   hard drive and restoring disks. If you have a back up then it is more
>   easy to revert to previous version. For it you have to first backup
>   your data and perform a clean install of Windows 7 from the
>   installation discs, or from the recovery disc partition created by
>   your computer vendor.
>
> If you want to try it I would suggest you that you should do it on a
>   separate drive and make sure that the data cable is not connected with
>   Windows 7 drive, or you can try it on a seperate dummy pc that is of no
>   use for you, image backups might also work but it needs extra caution
>   plus there are chances that it may fail.