# Undo system upgrade

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to Windows 7 after installing Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/335571/how-to-revert-to-windows-7-after-installing-windows-8)

I am not happy with windows 8 currently and thus I am wishing to either dual boot or undo my upgrade.Is it possible?

Comment: See: [How to revert to Windows 7 after installing Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/335571/how-to-revert-to-windows-7-after-installing-windows-8), and [Reverting from Windows 8 to Windows 7 or going back to dual boot](http://superuser.com/questions/336475/reverting-from-windows-8-to-windows-7-or-going-back-to-dual-boot?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Undoing an upgrade is **not possible**. Your best bet is to back up your data and do a fresh install of Windows 7.

In addition, if you purchased the Windows 8 upgrade, dual booting is not possible (or is at least against the licensing agreement). The Windows 8 upgrade is designed to update an existing Win 7 instance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is **Dual Booting** that is possible.

The other way if you like **experimenting** then make an Image of the current OS and keep it in say other HDD(external or Internal) and restore it later on.It is possible by creating a system image using **NORTON GHOST**.The Link http://norton-ghost.en.softonic.com/

You can also create a **Bootable Norton Ghost CD** and then select the ISO from HDD and restore
the image and the OS instance will be back and running

Its a wonderful tool  to create  and keep images of OS as an ISO Format and then use it when you require.